# Image centered, height or width = 100% of the original image, image Overflow Responsive Divs

Tags: html, css, image, overflow, centering

I need to make a page with different Divs to make rows and columns. First row has three divs (width=33% and height=25%). I want to center (vertically and horizontally) the images without rescaling them (I'm using overflow:hidden to crop the rest of the image).
How do I center them?
This is what I'm writing:

CSS

```
div.hiddenrow1 {
width: 33%;
height: 25%;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<!--Row 1-->
<!--Air 1-->
<div class="hiddenrow1"><img src="Gifs/gifs pom twix/air_skate.gif" class="img" /></div>

<!--Air 2-->
<div class="hiddenrow1"><img src="Gifs/gifs pom twix/air_sea.gif" class="img" /></div>

<!--Air 3-->
<div class="hiddenrow1"><img src="Gifs/gifs pom twix/air_diving.gif" class="img" /></div>
```

Also, 
for the second row, is it possible to position divs as if they were columns? Here is an image for the final structure I'm designing.
[image: structure]

PS: I don't know how to use tables and I'm not sure is they are suitable for this, but I'm open to all go in all directions I would appreciate if someone could give me a hand.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mw7rj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can achieve what your after using tables.

```
<table border="1" style="height:25%; width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:33.33333333%">1</td>
        <td style="width:33.33333333%">2</td>
        <td style="width:33.33333333%">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="height:50%; width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:15%" rowspan="3"></td>
        <td style="width:15%"></td>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td style="width:15%"></td>
        <td style="width:15%" rowspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="height:25%; width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%"></td>
        <td style="width:20%"></td>
        <td style="width:20%"></td>
        <td style="width:20%"></td>
        <td style="width:20%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Use css to add images to each td in your stylesheet, centring them like so:

```
td
{
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(http://wac.450f.edgecastcdn.net/80450F/arcadesushi.com/files/2014/04/Goat-Simulator-Coffee-Stain-Studios.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/yLqz4/1

```
<table>
<!--Row 1-->
<!--Air 1-->
    <tr><td>
<div class="hiddenrow1"><img src="Gifs/gifs pom twix/air_skate.gif" class="img" /></div>
        </td></tr>

<!--Air 2-->
<tr><td>
    <div class="hiddenrow1"><img src="Gifs/gifs pom twix/air_sea.gif" class="img" /></div>
    </td></tr>
<!--Air 3-->
    <tr><td>
<div class="hiddenrow1"><img src="Gifs/gifs pom twix/air_diving.gif" class="img" /></div>
        </td></tr>
</table>
```

the above is the fiddle from what i understood. have a look at it and post me if u want any help further. i cant see any images, please check the source files

Comment: Thank you! I tried but the images organizes as a column and not as a row, as you can see in this declinated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yLqz4/4/ ... I've just added an image to the question to explain the grid.

Comment: here are two fiddles that are in columns. please have a look and let me know any help.  http://jsfiddle.net/yLqz4/5/   and   http://jsfiddle.net/yLqz4/6/

Comment: Thank you. But The images should be real size and fit inside the dynamic grid. Like this and without breakink the rows: http://jsfiddle.net/Mw7rj/ also avoiding different heights (clipping them if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To control the position and overflow of your images, put them in as CSS background images instead of inline `<img>` tags, and use background-position: 50% 50%:

HTML

```
<div class="hiddenrow1 air1"></div>
<div class="hiddenrow1 air2"></div>
<div class="hiddenrow1 air3"></div>
```

CSS

```
.hiddenrow1 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 33%; height: 25%; /* ...etc... */
    display: inline-block;
}

.air1 {
   background-image: url('Gifs/gifs%20pom%20twix/air_skate.gif');
}
.air2 {
   background-image: url('Gifs/gifs%20pom%20twix/air_sea.gif');
}
.air3 {
   background-image: url('Gifs/gifs%20pom%20twix/air_diving.gif');
}
```

For your "is it possible to position divs as if they were columns" question -- I feel like I'm probably not understanding what you're asking for, there, because the  code you're already using should do exactly that: each div is 33% of the parent node's width, and with inline-block they won't force a clear the way `display:block` would, so they should appear as a single row with three columns.  (But note that including borders or margins on your .air* divs may cause the third item to wrap to the next line, unless you also use `box-sizing: border-box`.)

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I did exactly what you told me to (created a new doc) but now the images don't show. I know the links are correct because if I add a text rule like "font-family" and add some text in the html on the .air1, part of the image appears (and it seems centered).
Like this...
    .air1 {
 background-image: url('../../../POM/Video/input/gifs/tumblr_m5ggeyDtfX1qlgyqyo1_500.gif');
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

it just doesn't seem to assume the width and heigh of the .hiddenrow class

Comment: Setting heights as percentages can have iffy results if there isn't a defined parent node with an explicit height.  Here is your fiddle with an explicit height (and some extraneous css removed; you don't need overflow:hidden for example):  http://jsfiddle.net/Ls6k6/2/

Comment: And again with a demonstration of % height within a container: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls6k6/3/